# Initializer list for const char* const ptr;

Tags: c++, constants

Can any one help me in writing the following constructor that will do DEEP COPY

```
class simple
{
    const char*  const name;
    simple(char *n);
};
```

If I try:

```
simple(char *n):name(new char[strlen(n)]) { 
  strcpy(name,n); 
} // it is error
```

Comment: To put it simply, that is a very simple constructor. Where is your attempt?

Comment: I need to allocate a memory , in the same time I have to initialize it with user provided. If I try
simple(char *n):name(new char[strlen(n)]) 
{
strcpy(name,n);
}
// it is error

Comment: Looks like b4hand gave you what you needed.

Comment: Change the type of `name` to `std::string`? It will make the copy for you.

Answer (score 2):

```
simple::simple(char *n) : name(n) {}
```

For a deep copy you could use `strdup`:

```
simple::simple(char *n) : name(strdup(n)) {}
```

Or if you don't have strdup you could just as easily implement it yourself.

Comment: In  this case it will be shallow copy?